# When is ETH needed in a contract?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to work out when ETH is **needed** and hence when the modifier **payable** is needed in a function. I read through the "documentation" and various jumbled up references to payable, but I cannot see any clear statement about when ETH is needed and when payable therefore is needed.

I assume that payable is needed when a state variable is modified. Is there any other condition requiring ETH and hence the word payable to be stated?

From what I know now -

State Variable **Update** - ETH needed - **payable** specified

Other variable actions (eg local, or reading *only*) - *no* ETH needed - payable *not* specified.

Answer (score 1):

`payable` is only necessary when you want a transaction that calls a function to accept eth as payment. If `payable` is omitted, the only change is that calls to the function that are transferring eth will fail. Calls to functions with `payable` don't fail if eth is sent during the call.

Comment: Has someone a code example? Does this mean that Ethereum dapps are free to use in terms of blockchain costs if only state variables are updated or read?

Comment: No, the sender of the tx still has to pay transaction fees. This is completely separate from payable and the amount of wei sent in a transaction

Comment: OK, I had thought payable referred to txn fees.

Answer (score 0):

A contract only needs ETH if it will keep and eventually transfer the ETH.

*Contracts can execute code because the sender of the transaction pays for all the execution.*

A contract only needs `payable` on the functions that it wants to receive ETH at.  A contract can also receive ETH during its creation, only if the constructor is `payable`.

`payable` was added to Solidity to avoid ETH being accidentally sent and permanently stuck in contracts that did not have a way to withdraw the ETH.